# How to calculate mean signed error using pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

Let's say I have following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['x',  42, 50, 68, 12],
                   ['y',  51, 60, 79, 22],
                   ['z',  43, 50, 58, 12],
                   ['w',  46, 70, 88, 22],
                   ['xy', 38, 40, 69, 22],
                   ['xz', 39, 40, 49, 12]],
                  columns=['system', 'Experimental', 'Prediction1', 'Prediction2', 'Prediction3'])
```

How can I calculate signed error? I could not find any info regarding this at all.

Comment: That's not a valid frame constructor. And which mean signed error are you looking for?

Comment: To be honest I even don't know exactly what signed error means. I could not find any info regarding this

Comment: The Mean Signed Error, more commonly known as the Mean Signed Deviation, is basically the same as the Mean Squared Error, except each term is **not** squared. Please look at the link in my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to calculate [this statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_signed_deviation). If so, you can define your own function and then pass in your predictions to compare against the observed values.

You did not mention which column in `df` is the observed value of the dependent variable, so I am assuming it's `Experimental` and I'm comparing it against `Prediction1`.

```py
# Define custom function
def msd(y_true, y_pred):
    return (y_pred - y_true).mean()

# Mean Signed Deviation of 'Experimental' and 'Prediction1'
msd(df['Experimental'], df['Prediction1'])
> 8.5
```